# Create a trigger that sends an alert on a column of a particular record, Oracle

Tags: oracle, web-applications, oracle11g, triggers, alert

I have a table as follows:

```
ID    First_Name      Last_Name         Master
1     Tom             Sawyer            Yes
2     John            Jay               Maybe
```

How can I create a trigger that sends an alert on update/delete of column Master of record with ID=1?

No alert should be send if update/delete is done for any other records.

If such a trigger cannot be created, is there any other mechanism that can be used to setup such an alert?

Comment: what do you mean by "alert"? What are you expecting to happen? Is this an error message that should be returned to the user doing the update/delete, or a mail sent behind the scenes, or something else?

Comment: @Boneist An email alert.

Comment: Have you tried creating a trigger? What bit are you stuck on?